# Navigating to the view taking much time on notifications click

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I am using FCM notifications to xamarin. forms android and `CrossFirebasePushNotification`. When notification is clicked user has to navigate to some other view. Functionally everything is fine, but navigating to the specific view is taking too much time around 4-5 seconds while tapping on the notification.

Here is my main activity.

```
    [Activity(Label = "somename", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```

Notification open event:

```
 CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened += (s, p) =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Opened");

                    string id = string.Empty;

                    string senderName = string.Empty;

                    foreach (var data in p.Data)
                    {
                        if (data.Key == "id") { id = data.Value.ToString(); }

                        if (data.Key == "isChannelChat") { IsPersonalChat = Convert.ToInt32(data.Value.ToString()) == 0; }

                        if (data.Key == "SenderName") { senderName = data.Value.ToString(); }

                        Debug.WriteLine($"{data.Key} : {data.Value}");
                    }

                    if (p.Data.ContainsKey("id"))
                    {
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var userModel = new UserModel();

                                if (IsPersonalChat)
                                {
                                    userModel.Id = Guid.Parse(id);

                                    userModel.FullName = senderName;

                                    userModel.TypeId = 1;

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    userModel.ChannelId = Guid.Parse(id);

                                    userModel.ChannelName = senderName;

                                    userModel.TypeId = 2;
                                }

                                if (userModel.TypeId == 1)
                                {
                                    Helper.NavigateTo(new ChatView("Personal Chat",userModel));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Helper.NavigateTo(new ChatView("Group",userModel));
                                }
                            }

                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                };
```

Is there any thing that I am missing?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms app itself taking 5-6 seconds to start app. You shouldn't wonder if your app taking same time.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @r15, But is there any workaround to minimize that startup time.

Comment: In your ChatView pages are you fetching data/calling services?

Comment: Yes, I am fetching the data from the server

Comment: That might cause the issue. Try remove/comment that and observe how much time taking. If it making any different then you can try something like threading etc..

Comment: Maybe that could be one of the reason, I will check with that. Thank you for the help  @r15